# Bash _cd Autocomplete to Start from Directory

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

I want to cd to some directory within /long/path/name/.  I would like a function `cd2` that

- Takes an argument
- `cd`s to /long/path/name/$argument
- *And* autocompletes from `cd2 <tab><tab>` as if I had run `cd /long/path/name/; cd <tab><tab>`

It is the third requirement that I am having trouble with.  I can get a function to autocomplete only the subdirectories of /long/path/name/, but I cannot continue tabbing to get subdirectories of that subdirectory.

I would like to autocomplete as if I had typed `cd` in /long/path/name/.  The ideal would be to easily adapt `_cd` to do the job, but that may not be possible.

I have been using the code below, but I have to admit that I am new to bash autocomplete and do not fully understand the `_cdFromDir` syntax.

```
function cd2() {
    cd /long/path/name/$@ ;
}

_cdFromDir() {

  local cur prev opts
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
  opts=$(ls /long/path/name/)
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
  return 0

}

complete -F _cdFromDir cd2
```

Comment: well written question. I don't have an answer to this but GOOD JOB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my ubuntu system, `complete -p cd` shows:

```
complete -o nospace -F _cd cd
```

To do what you seem to want to do, I can define:

```
cd2top='/long/path/name'
cd2(){ builtin cd "${@:-"$cd2top"}"; }
_cd2(){ [[ $PWD =~ ^"$cd2top" ]] || cd "$cd2top"; _cd; }
complete -o nospace -F _cd2 cd2
```

Comment: This solved it, thank you!  On my system, the complete statement is "complete -F _cd2 cd2" but otherwise works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

jhnc's answer is excellent and provides 95% of the work.  There were a couple small issues I fixed:

- After running the command, `cd -` did not take me back to the directory where I ran the command from.  (This is because of the `cd` in the autocomplete function.)
- The command did not autocomplete within the directory where it takes you.  So if it takes me to `/a/` and I am in `/a/b/c/` and want to get to `/a/d/e/`, I could not get autocomplete.

```
cd2() {
  builtin cd "${@:-"/long/path/name/"}"

  # Change directory back to original PWD if autocomplete changed it
  if [[ -e ~/cd2TempFile.txt ]]; then
    read origDir < ~/cd2TempFile.txt
    OLDPWD=$origDir
    rm ~/cd2TempFile.txt
  fi
}

_cd2(){

  if [[ ! $PWD =~ ^"/long/path/name$" ]]; then
    echo $PWD > ~/cd2TempFile.txt
    cd "/long/path/name/";
  fi

  _cd;
}

complete -F _cd2 cd2
```